# Regex: Counted occurences in different places

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Is regex capable of matching patterns which might be separated by a different pattern?

E.g.: `A{3}B{2}` would match AAABB. How can I make it match ABABA?

As this is just an example, I am not looking for a way to match all permutations of AAABB, but to learn a generic method. :-)

Comment: You could assert 3 times an A and 2 times a B, then match `[AB]+`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: @BadHorsie: Great resource, thanks. I did not yet come up with a solution, but I learned something useful there. :)

Comment: @BadHorsie: After accepting another answer: Yes, your link had the tools needed to solve my task. Knowing the syntax and finding a solution are different beasts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
^(?=(?:B*A){3}B*$)(?=(?:A*B){2}A*$)[AB]{5}$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/oNoYHb/1)

**Explantion:**

```
^               # beginning of string
  (?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after exactly 3 A:
    (?:             # non capture group
      B*              # 0 or more B
      A               # 1 A
    ){3}            # end group, must appear 3 times
    B*              # 0 or more B
    $               # end of string
  )               # end of string
  (?=(?:A*B){2}A*$)     # same explanation as above for exactly 2 B
  [AB]{5}       # we must have 5 A or B
$               # end of string
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Maybe you could add/copy a high level explanation: As far as I understood: You first look for 3 groups of A with any(\*) Bs in between, then look for 2 groups of Bs with any(\*) As in between, and finally look for a total of 5 A-or-Bs.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=A{3}B{2})[AB]+
```

(?=A{3}B{2}) - Positive lookahead of the given string to make sure we have exactly 3 A's and 2 B's. If this results in true then it starts looking for [AB]+ . This strictly matches the AAABB.

https://regex101.com/r/6xcNb7/3

Updated as requested and this should match other permutations.

```
(?=(?:B*A){3}B*$)|(?=(?:A*B){2}A*$)[AB]{5}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there seems to be an issue - the Regex finds the first occurance of AAABB, and the n any subsequent As and Bs. It doesn't match ABABA or BBAAA.

Comment: `(?=(?:B*A){3}B*$)|(?=(?:A*B){2}A*$)[AB]{5}` - I see I came up almost same answer as Toto

Comment: @Zsolt - Updated the post.